# Which algorithm or statistical method will be best?

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, neural-network, statistics, deep-learning

I have a table of 21 students (A1…A21) and their 25 characteristics (table 1) and I have another matrix  (table 2) which shows if a student likes another student or not (0 means likes and 100 means dislike).

How can I find the least no. of characteristics that can give me similar distance in space as the likeability matrix?

**For Example:**
If we get 5 dimensions with characteristics C1, C3, C4, C5, C10, then the points A1,..A21 when plotted for these characteristics will have the proportional distance as the likeability matrix.

For example, if A3 and A2 have a small distance between them in that 5D characteristics space, then they will have a corresponding smaller distance/value in the likeability matrix.

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGoPp.jpg)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gLWd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can make this look like a well-known statistical problem, but you have made assumptions (that similar students like each other), I will make further assumptions, and most of the solutions to the statistical problem are not very respectable, so you should take the results with a pinch of salt.

With 21 students, you have 21*20/2 = 210 pairs of students. Treat each pair as a separate observation. You have a likeability value for that pair. For each pair compute, for each characteristic, the absolute value of the difference between the values for each of the two students. This gives you a vector of 25 elements for each observation. You will now try and predict the 210 likeabilities given the 210 25-long vectors of absolute differences.

Procedures for this go under the names of all-subsets regression and stepwise regression. See https://www.r-bloggers.com/variable-selection-using-automatic-methods/ and https://www.r-bloggers.com/variable-selection-using-automatic-methods/. One way to compute these is to use the free open source statistical package R from https://www.r-project.org/.

For each possible selection of variables you can use linear regression to predict likeability from the vector of absolute differences. From that linear regression you can get a measure of how good the prediction is, and so whether that particular selection of variables was any good or not. All subsets regression uses a variation on branch and bound to work out, for each N, the set of variables of size N which predicts best. Stepwise regression starts off with a possibly incomplete selection of variables and performs a sort of hillclimb, adding or subtracting one variable from the set at each stage, trying all of the variables and choosing the one that gives the best prediction. Typically you start with no variables and add one variable at a time, or start will all variables, and remove one variable at a time. Stepwise selection isn't guaranteed to find the absolute best selection of variables that all subsets regression will find, but all subsets regression can be very expensive.

From this you will get a best selection of variables (probably one best selection for each number of variables) and you may get some indication of statistical significance. You have broken so many rules about multiple testing and independence (inflating 21 observations to 210) that you shouldn't take any statistical significance seriously.  If you want some idea of whether you are looking at real information or prettied-up random noise, automate the procedure and see what it looks like on fake data where there is no underlying effect at all, and perhaps on fake data where you have constructed data from which there is an underlying effect that you know about because you have constructed it. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Permutation_tests